# Predicate logic proof problem

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Where the domain of the variables are Real Numbers, determine the truth value for the following:

$$ \forall x \exists y(y^2-x<200) $$

I don't understand how to formally prove this problem. Since $y^2\geq 0$ it would stand to reason that any $x< 0$ could disprove this statement. I tried to prove it true by using one case where $x=3$ and $y=3 \therefore  9-3<900 $ which makes it True.

How should I tackle a problem like this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd rewrite it as $\forall x\exists y(y^2<200+x)$. This basically says that every real number is strictly greater than some square.

Comment: You can't prove $\forall x\cdots$ true by considering only one $x$. If it's true you need to prove it for _every_ $x$. You can prove it _false_ with a single counterexample, however.

Comment: Check what happens if we let $x=-1000$.

Comment: Not any $x<0$,but certainly any $x<-200$.

Comment: So basically by rewriting it as $ \forall x \exists y(y^2<200+x) $ I need to choose an $x$ such that the statement is false and therefore has a false truth value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to understand the statement $$ \forall x \exists y(y^2-x<200) $$ is to think of it as a game.  One player takes the $\forall$ quantifiers and one takes the $\exists$ quantifiers.  The $\forall$ player is trying to make the statement at the end (the $y^2-x<200$) false, and the $\exists$ player is trying to make it true.  Each quantifier, $\exists$ or $\forall$, is one move in the game.

In this game, the $\forall$ player moves first, and picks a value for $x$.  Then the $\exists$ player moves second, and picks a value for $y$.  The entire statement, including the quantifiers, is true if the $\exists$ player can always make $y^2-x < 200$.

Suppose the $\forall$ player picks $x=17$.  Then the $\exists$ player can win by picking $y=10$, since $10^2 - 17 < 200$.

Suppose the $\forall$ player picks $x=2$.  Can the $\exists$ player pick a $y$ that still makes $y^2-x < 200$?

Can the $\forall$ player make a move that leaves the $\exists$ player without a winning reply?  That's the question you are supposed to answer.

---

Here's my favorite example:  The statement $$\forall x\exists y (\text{$y$ is the mother of $x$})$$ is true, because whoever $\forall$ picks in move 1, $\exists$ can win by picking that person's mother.  Suppose $\forall$ picks $x$ equal to Angela Merkel; then $\exists$ wins by picking $y$ equal to Angela Merkel's mother.

But the statement $$\exists y\forall x (\text{$y$ is the mother of $x$})$$ is false, because now $\exists$ must go first, and she has no winning move. Suppose she picks $y$ equal to Angela Merkel's mother.  Then $\forall$ can win by picking $x$ equal to someone who is not Angela Merkel or one of Merkel's siblings; say George W. Bush.  Of course if $\exists$ picks Barbara Bush in her move, $\forall$ must not pick George W. Bush; he should pick someone else, like say Sisqo.

---

You asked in comments for an example with an implication.  Let's consider $$\forall x\exists y (\text{$x$ is even}  \to \text {xy = 2}).$$

The $\forall$ player moves first. If he picks an odd number for $x$ he loses immediately, because then regardless of what $\exists$ does, the implication $\text{$x$ is even}  \to xy=2$ is vacuously true (the antecedent is false, so the entire implication is true), and the $\forall$ player loses when the final statement is true.  So if $\forall$ wants to win he had better pick an even number!  Suppose he picks $x=2$.  Then $\exists$ can answer with $y=1$.  And suppose he picks $x=4$; then $\exists$ can answer with $\frac12$ (if that is allowed; it may be clear from context, or it may be stated explicitly what moves are allowed.)  But if $\forall$ picks $x=0$, he wins no matter what $\exists$ does, and so the quantified statement is *false*.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I didn't consider order when I tried to interpret this question. Thanks. So if I choose say $x = -201$ then there is no $y$ that could prove the statement true. Therefore the statement is false right?

Comment: Exactly right.  ${}{}{}$

Comment: Okay I got it! If you don't mind, how should I think of a statement that involves implication? For example: $ \forall x \exists y ( x \rightarrow xy ) $ (I made it up but I have a complicated problem sort of like this)?

Comment: You can do the same thing: $\forall$ picks an $x$, and then $\exists$ picks a $y$, and then you evaluate $x\to xy$ to see if it is true or false; if true, $\exists$ has won, and if false, $\forall$ has won. And the entire statement $\forall x\exists y(x\to xy)$ is true if $\exists$ can always win. I will add an example to the post.

Comment: Okay thanks I got it!

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. After I wrote it I decided it probably was not helpful and planned to delete it. I must have posted it by accident.  I'm glad I was wrong!

Comment: It's much easier to follow what's going on now... Thanks for the help.